# Same application in google app engine managed in two different emails

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm quite new to GAE, just started with it.
I make an application in gae and now my application is almost done 
but in this application i use my personal gmail, some friend join with me and I want in the future my friend can run and managed the same application but on their email.

so i want to ask,
Could the same application in google app engine, run and managed in two different account gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you go to the [Cloud Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and select your project, you should see *Permissions* in the menu on the left.  There you can add another Member who is either an Owner, or can edit or just view the project.

I'm not sure what you mean by *running* in two different accounts: it will run under the app (project) ID defined in the deployment descriptor, which is defined by the developer.